# Entity Framework Core take one and skip other duplicate item in a table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table that contains a list of `string` and many item in the table have the same `string` with a different `ID`, Now I want to take all the items from the table but not more than one items with the same `string`.

## Example Table

```
id    -   string
------------------
 1   ---   A 
 2   ---   B 
 3   ---   B 
 4   ---   C 
 5   ---   D 
 6   ---   D 
 7   ---   F
```

after the query the list should look like

```
A, B, C, D, F
```

How can I do that using LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, I suppose:

`var result = Context.yourTable.Select(t => t.fieldName).Distinct();`

So, basically, your query is getting only distinct values for 'fieldName' (whatever that may be in your case).